# Jenkins Credentials Plugin and Maven

Tags: maven, jenkins

Trying to get Jenkins (2.426.3) with Credentials Plugin and Maven work together.
Goal is hide credentials from Jenkins logs and Git.

Used Freestyle project.
Have credentials declared like this:
[Screenshot from Jenkins UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3At4.png).

Scope is global.

In pom.xml have them like this:

```
...
<clientID>${clientid}</clientID>
<clientSECRET>${clientsecret}</clientSECRET>
...
...
```

And values on build not passed to pom.xml

If I will specify them in Maven Properties (-Dclientid=XXXXXXX -Dclientsecret=YYYYYYY) then build will be successful.

Somehow same setup in really old Jenkins working (installation 6y old w/o updates).

Will appreciate any hint!